# Book about barbedwire robot guardian to space portal jumping teen?

Tags: identification-request

Anyone know the name of this series?

Back in the late 80's or early 90's I read a series about a galactic empire that used ground based portals to travel between planets. There was some issue and all the portals stopped working. Travel between planets was then only possible by spaceship. However, due to the speeds and acceleration/deceleration your body is destroyed in the process and has to be reconstructed at the other end; a resurrection of sorts. A galactic religious group holds a near monopoly on this process.

Fast-forward a couple hundred years. The protagonist is a teen girl that somehow learned something about the defunct portals and manages to travel through them. She is on a journey to a location where she can share this info with the galaxy. Of course the space church does not want that to happen as they will lose their monopoly on space travel and all the political and financial perks that come with it.

The space church sets out to capture her and extract the information with extreme prejudice. There is a cat and mouse between her and her companions' travel through the portals and the space church's resurrection space ship travel.

The space church had tons of resources. The girl has this mysterious barbedwire robot (warbot might be better) that turns up from time to time when she is in a jam  to dispatch her pursuers.

I can't remember author or name of this series. I think the robot was called a/the shriek or something like that.

Does anyone have an idea what I am talking about? I want to get it for a gift.

Comment: Are you sure about it being a series? Do you remember the total number of books in the series?

Comment: @CinCout From the answer below it appears it was a series but I was recalling the 3rd book.  I never the first 2.  Might pick them up for myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [***Endymion***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endymion_(Simmons_novel)) by Dan Simmons, the third in a series starting with [*Hyperion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperion_(Simmons_novel)).

- “Back in the late 80s or early 90s I read a series”

  The four books in the series are [*Hyperion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperion_(Simmons_novel)) (1989), *The Fall of Hyperion* (1990), [*Endymion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endymion_(Simmons_novel)) (1996) and *The Rise of Endymion* (1998).
- “about a galactic empire that used ground based portals to travel between planets. There was some issue and all the portals stopped working. Travel between planets was then only possible by spaceship.”

  > The Concourse had been sliced into a thousand separate segments by the Fall of the WorldWeb farcaster network; the Tethys had simply ceased to exist, the connecting portals useless. [*Endymion*, p. 26]
- “However, due to the speeds and acceleration/deceleration your body is destroyed in the process and has to be reconstructed at the other end; a resurrection of sorts.”

  > “You will have command of our newest and most advanced courier ship. Captain,” Marusyn is saying. “It is similar to the one which brought you to Pacem system, except that it can hold six passengers, it is armed to the level of your former torchship, and it has an automated resurrection system.” [p. 73]
- “A galactic religious group holds a near monopoly on this process.”

  > “The robot system is regrettable, my son. But the ship may carry you to places where the Pax
  > and the Church do not exist. We cannot deny you resurrection simply because you are beyond the reach of God’s servants.” [pp. 83–84]
- “The protagonist is a teen girl”

  Aenea, aged twelve at the start of *Endymion*.
- “that somehow learned something about the defunct portals and manages to travel through them.”

  > “The fact that the child known as Aenea—or someone or something traveling with her—was able to escape via a farcaster that has not worked for almost three standard centuries could not have been anticipated by you or by any other officer working with you or under your command. The fact that the farcasters could resume operation at all is, of course, of grave concern to the Pax Command and to the Church.” [p. 207]
- “The space church sets out to capture her”

  > “capturing Aenea is the single most important thing on the Pax's agenda” [p. 25]
- “The girl has this mysterious barbedwire robot”

  > “Something huge is standing not three meters from me in the whipping sand. Its legs are planted wide. It looks like a giant in barbed combat armor—a giant with too many arms.” [p. 106]
- “I think the robot was called the shriek or something like that.”

  > “To my knowledge, in legend and the old records, the creature called the Shrike never left Hyperion—usually staying in the area within a few hundred kilometers around the Time Tombs.” [p. 124]